# How to use the “Change REST Url” rule in Infopath 2010 when web service url changes between different environments

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

I tried to submit this question on StackOverflow but I had no luck. Here is how it goes :

First of all, I'd like not to use code in the Infopath form template, if possible.

Second, what i'm really trying to achieve is passing parameters (as url params) to my REST web service.

Third, we develop the web services concurrently to the form template.

So, we have 3 SharePoint environments (local dev, QA and prod), and we have to change the data connection files (udc) when deploying so that the Infopath in the QA environment calls the web service in the QA environment, etc.

As far as I know, the only way to pass dynamic parameters to a REST web service is to use the Concat fonction in the formula for the "Change REST url" rule. But the web service URL is automatically copied as a string and hardcoded into the formula which is not what I want.

ex:  `Concat("http://mydomain/webservice?param=",field1)`

Has anyone found a way to dynamically pass url params to a rest web service in a multi environment?

Comment: Any for you regarding the solution?

Comment: Nope, didn't find any solution.  I still hardcode the url, unfortunatly, and document this in a deploy plan.